# How to validate if a name is contained in a password

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have a problem where I need to prevent the password provided by the user from containing his name or parts of his name. The rules are as follows:

1. It cannot have any user's first or last name in the password
2. There cannot be any part greater than or equal to 3 characters of the user's first or last name in the password.

The code I have so far is this one that can only validate rule 1.

```
fun containsUsername(data: PasswordData): Boolean {
    val partsUsername = data.username.split(" ").joinToString("|")
    val namePattern = Regex("""(?i).*($partsUsername).*""")

    return namePattern.containsMatchIn(data.password)
}
```

Examples to facilitate understanding:

```
fun main() {
     val username = "Maria Antonia dos Santos"
     val password1 = "AbcMariaXyz" // Invalid password due to "Maria"
     val password2 = "AntoniaMaria" // Invalid password due to "Maria"
     val password3 = "Maria123" // Invalid password due to "Maria"
     val password4 = "AntoniaSenha" // Invalid password due to "Antonia"
     val password5 = "Dos_123" // Invalid password due to "Dos"
     val password6 = "SantosAbc" // Invalid password due to "Santos"
     val password7 = "OniSenha" // Invalid password due to "Oni"
     val password8 = "MarSenha" // Invalid password due to "Mar"
    
     println(containsUsername(password1, username)) // true
     println(containsUsername(password2, username)) // true
     println(containsUsername(password3, username)) // true
     println(containsUsername(password4, username)) // true
     println(containsUsername(password5, username)) // true
     println(containsUsername(password6, username)) // true
     println(containsUsername(password7, username)) // true
     println(containsUsername(password8, username)) // true
}
```

Comment: Rule 1 seems unnecessary as anything that it catches would also be caught by rule 2. Also neither rule seems to explain why `Dos_123` or `AntoniaSenha` are invalid, as they are not the first or last name.

Comment: I understand, rule 1 really seems unnecessary, if you think about it. But in the case of "Dos_123" it is because of the "dos" in the last name, and "AntoniaPassword" is because of the last name "Antonia".

Comment: @AdrianHHH Rule 1 would catch passwords containing a name such as "Bo" or any other name shorter than 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) solution that fits, you could perhaps just search through the password string. This is in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (which the question *was* tagged with) since I know [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) even worse than I know javascript, but it's hopefully not hard to convert it if this solution would work for you.

```js
function containsUsername(name, password) {
  // convert the strings to lowercase for easier searching
  // spaces should apparently not count, so split the name into parts
  nameparts = name.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  lpwd = password.toLowerCase();
  
  for(part of nameparts) {
    // check at most 3 characters at a time from each part
    end = part.length > 3 ? part.length - 3 : 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= end; ++i) {
      if(lpwd.indexOf(part.substr(i, 3)) != -1) return true;
    }
  }
  return false; // no match found
}

username = "Maria Antonia dos Santos";
  
const passwords = [
  "AbcMariaXyz", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "AntoniaMaria", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "Maria123", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "AntoniaSenha", // Invalid password due to "Antonia"
  "Dos_123", // Invalid password due to "Dos"
  "SantosAbc", // Invalid password due to "Santos"
  "OniSenha", // Invalid password due to "Oni"
  "MarSenha", // Invalid password due to "Mar"
];
     
for (pwd of passwords) {
  console.log("testing " + pwd);
  res = containsUsername(username, pwd);
  console.log(res);
}
```

Here's a more verbose version that returns the part of the string it got a match on, or an empty string if the password is free of hits. I added some debug printouts to make it easier to see what it's doing:

```js
function containsUsername(name, password) {
  // convert the strings to lowercase for easier searching
  // spaces should apparently not count, so split the name into parts
  nameparts = name.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  lpwd = password.toLowerCase();
  
  for(part of nameparts) {
    // check at most 3 characters at a time from each part
    console.log(" Trying substrings of \"" + part + "\"");
    end = part.length > 3 ? part.length - 3 : 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= end; ++i) {
      subpart = part.substr(i, 3);
      console.log("  checking \"" + subpart + "\"");
      if(lpwd.indexOf(subpart) != -1) return subpart;
    }
  }
  return ""; // no match found
}

username = "Maria Antonia dos Santos";
  
const passwords = [
  "AbcMariaXyz", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "AntoniaMaria", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "Maria123", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "AntoniaSenha", // Invalid password due to "Antonia"
  "Dos_123", // Invalid password due to "Dos"
  "SantosAbc", // Invalid password due to "Santos"
  "OniSenha", // Invalid password due to "Oni"
  "MarSenha", // Invalid password due to "Mar"
  "A An", // Valid
];
     
for (pwd of passwords) {
  console.log("Testing password \"" + pwd + "\"");
  res = containsUsername(username, pwd);
  console.log(" Verdict: " + (res.length ? "NOK, \"" + res + "\" found in \"" + pwd + "\"" : "OK"));
}
```